# Graph API User Link leads to Content Not Available page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

So I'm messing around with facebook's Graph API explorer and I came upon a very odd issue. 
All I've really done is really explore /me?fields=link so that I can get a link to my own profile. 
I get a URL based on my app_scoped_user_id, I click the link and I get to a facebook page that says "This content is not available right now".

The funny thing is - I sent the link to a friend of mine and he says the URL works; it redirected him to my real profile.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you logged in to Facebook at that point?

Comment: Yes, with the same account that I just browsed the explorer with

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having this problem? I saw exactly the same thing and the problem just resolved itself after I logged out of my app, deleted the app storage and restarted it.